# test for spacebar value in text input

Tags: php

Is there a way to test if the spacebar has been pressed in a form text input. I know nthe value or keycode is 32 and have tried various options using statements like:

```
elseif($rec =='' || $rec == 32 || $rec == ' ')
```

but still not recognized. I would appreciate any help with this and the code I posted is just part of the relevant code I am using to check for value. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this in PHP?

Comment: @prash Well evidently; look at the tags, and the snippet looks more like PHP than anything else.

Comment: @JamWaffles PHP is a server-side language, not client-side.

Comment: I know, what's your point?

Comment: Where do you want to check the value on server or on client?

Comment: I think I was being stupid.

Comment: @Prash actually I'm with you. He said "test if the spacebar has been pressed in a form text input". He did not say "test for spaces in submitted data". So which is he looking for, js or php?

Comment: jeez guys, obviously the code is php and I thought my question was straight forward. I am obviously testing for value in input. Haha never been marked -3 for a straight forward question.

Comment: Then why did you tag javascript? confusing.

Comment: It should be php and quite honestly Tim, the answers are making it confusing. haha now it has reached -4. could be a new record

Comment: @Kuf thank you for that. However, it seems that there is no correct way to post a question at SO. Either people say it is too much, not enough or find some other grammatical error to throw at a user who is just posting for help. Thanks

Comment: i don't agree.. yea, people can seem harsh at first, but listening to their tips can only help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = '/\s/';
if (preg_match($pattern,)) {...}
```

using PHP [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$mystring = 'Hello world';
$findme   = ' ';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "no spaces :(";
} else {
    echo "Spacing out !!! :)";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `trim()` and `strstr()` functions. I thought it is what you need.

Comment: OP said he wants to test for spaces, not just trim all whitespace.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure he does know what exactly he wants...

Comment: If you are unsure, then leave a comment asking. No need to answer based upon guessing.